# Stripe - "Add a bank account" not displaying any other currency

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe-connect

Under "Customers" > "Bank accounts" it only shows USD for currency:

[SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoFB8.png)

Is this a bug or does it only support USD?

Answer (score 1):

**From Stripe:**

You can only accept funds in USD and only from U.S. bank accounts. In addition, your account must have a U.S./USD bank account to accept ACH payments. Although we do not offer ACH payments for other, this is something we currently working on. Stripe is always looking for ways to improve things for our users. For more information on ACH payments, please visit the link below:

https://support.stripe.com/questions/accepting-ach-payments-with-stripe

I know this isn't the information you wanted to hear, but if you have any other questions or concerns about Stripe, please feel free to get back in touch with me. I want to make sure you are taken care of.

Answer (score 0):

ACH is only available for a US USD bank account: https://stripe.com/docs/ach